# Where does "config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest" go in my Vagrantfile?

Tags: python, django, virtual-machine, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm setting up my first Django VM with Vanguard following [this guide](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/setup-a-django-vm-with-vagrant-virtualbox-and-chef/#comment-80739). Ran into an error:

> ==> djangovm: [2014-10-20T15:04:09+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
>   
> ==> djangovm: [2014-10-20T15:04:09+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
>   
> ==> djangovm: [2014-10-20T15:04:09+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
>   
> ==> djangovm: [2014-10-20T15:04:09+02:00] FATAL: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::LWRPBase

Found the answer here: [Vagrant & Chef: uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::LWRPBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678185/vagrant-chef-uninitialized-constant-chefresourcelwrpbase) which says to refer to this answer: [How to control the version of Chef that Vagrant uses to provision VMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325479/how-to-control-the-version-of-chef-that-vagrant-uses-to-provision-vms)

I'm just not sure where do I put:

> config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

in my Vagrantfile?

My Vagrant file looks like that tutorial link exactly at the moment:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :djangovm do |django_config|
    # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
    django_config.vm.box = "lucid64"

    # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
    # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
    django_config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid64.box"

    # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
    # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
    django_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
    django_config.vm.forward_port 8000, 8001

    # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path (relative
    # to this Vagrantfile), and adding some recipes and/or roles.
    #
    django_config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
      chef.add_recipe "apt"
      chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_wsgi"
      chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
      chef.add_recipe "git"
      chef.add_recipe "vim"
    #
    #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
    #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
     end
   end
 end
```

I tried adding it in like so:

```
# The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
# doesn't already exist on the user's system.
django_config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid64.box"

# This gets the latest version of Omnibus
config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
```

Then did `Vagrant Destroy` then `Vagrant Up` and still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it inside the `:djangovm` definition as you tried, but there you need to use

```
django_config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
```

Of course you also have to install the [vagrant-omnibus](https://github.com/opscode/vagrant-omnibus) too:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus
```

Btw, it is safer to lock down the Chef version to a known version so your provision won't explode when Chef releases new major versions. So for example:

```
django_config.omnibus.chef_version = "11.6.4"
```