# undefined method "cheffish" for nil:NilClass, when provisioning chef with vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to run a django-server in a Vagrant box using Chef, but I've been stuck on this for a few hours and can't find anything online. The relevant bit of my vagrantfile looks like this: (sorry for the poor indentation) Also, the box is running centos7.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
chef.add_recipe "apache2"
chef.add_recipe "apt"
chef.add_recipe "bluepill"
chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
chef.add_recipe "chef-sugar"
chef.add_recipe "chef_handler"
chef.add_recipe "cms-scanner"
chef.add_recipe "gunicorn"
chef.add_recipe "homebrew"
chef.add_recipe "install_from"
chef.add_recipe "iptables"
chef.add_recipe "logrotate"
chef.add_recipe "metachef"
chef.add_recipe "mysql"
chef.add_recipe "nginx"
chef.add_recipe "ohai"
chef.add_recipe "openssl"
chef.add_recipe "packagecloud"
chef.add_recipe "pacman"
chef.add_recipe "python"
chef.add_recipe "rbac"
chef.add_recipe "redis"
chef.add_recipe "runit"
chef.add_recipe "smf"
chef.add_recipe "windows"
chef.add_recipe "yum"
chef.add_recipe "yum-epel"
end
```

And I get this error when I run `vagrant provision`

```
 C:\Users\garrowa\Desktop\cms-vagrant>vagrant provision
    ==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
    ==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
    Generating chef JSON and uploading...
    ==> default: Running chef-solo...
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:53-04:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge
    ...
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:53-04:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.4.0 ***
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:53-04:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 4398
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[
    apache2]", "recipe[apt]", "recipe[bluepill]", "recipe[build-essential]", "recipe
    [chef-sugar]", "recipe[chef_handler]", "recipe[cms-scanner]", "recipe[gunicorn]"
    , "recipe[homebrew]", "recipe[install_from]", "recipe[iptables]", "recipe[logrot
    ate]", "recipe[metachef]", "recipe[mysql]", "recipe[nginx]", "recipe[ohai]", "re
    cipe[openssl]", "recipe[packagecloud]", "recipe[pacman]", "recipe[python]", "rec
    ipe[rbac]", "recipe[redis]", "recipe[runit]", "recipe[smf]", "recipe[windows]",
    "recipe[yum]", "recipe[yum-epel]"] from CLI options
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apache2], rec
    ipe[apt], recipe[bluepill], recipe[build-essential], recipe[chef-sugar], recipe[
    chef_handler], recipe[cms-scanner], recipe[gunicorn], recipe[homebrew], recipe[i
    nstall_from], recipe[iptables], recipe[logrotate], recipe[metachef], recipe[mysq
    l], recipe[nginx], recipe[ohai], recipe[openssl], recipe[packagecloud], recipe[p
    acman], recipe[python], recipe[rbac], recipe[redis], recipe[runit], recipe[smf],
     recipe[windows], recipe[yum], recipe[yum-epel]]
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apache2, apt
    , bluepill, build-essential, chef-sugar, chef_handler, cms-scanner, gunicorn, ho
    mebrew, install_from, iptables, logrotate, metachef, mysql, nginx, ohai, openssl
    , packagecloud, pacman, python, rbac, redis, runit, smf, windows, yum, yum-epel]

    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for localhost
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] INFO: Running start handlers
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] ERROR: undefined method `cheffish' for
    nil:NilClass
    ==> default: [2015-06-30T18:04:55-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeE
    rror: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
    Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
    output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

What really confuses me is that I can't find any references to cheffish anywhere in any of these cookbooks.

I've tried eliminating all `chef.add_recipe` lines except `ohai`, and alternatively `yum`, but I still get the same error. (I am running `vagrant reload` and `vagrant provision` between tries. I've also tried sshing into the box, removing the `cheffish` gem, running `vagrant provision`, and reinstalling the `cheffish` gem and running `vagrant provision`, but to no avail.

Comment: Cheffish is [part of Chef](https://github.com/chef/chef/commit/bf6340a113dd0c37e2084c70007d201742f11e9d#diff-ce5d78d20ca098b17602b9487c352109), so you're right its not getting pulled in by your cookbooks. I don't know why you would get that error though.

Comment: I'm experiencing this for the first time today as well - guessing it was introduced in 12.4.0.

Comment: I hate to say me too,  but me too.

Comment: @MattO you were right, I switched to 12.3.0 and now it works :)

Comment: Still a bug in 12.4.1. Also it's worth noting that if you set the log level of your chef provisioner to debug (chef.log_level = :debug), you'll likely see some other error. That cheffish thing is masking the real error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got it. As pointed out in the comments this problem is introduced in chef v. 12.4.0, I added the line `chef.version = "12.3.0"` to the provision block and now it's working.

Comment: And is it a bug in 12.4.0, or is it a backwards-compatibility break?

Comment: Setting in the Vagrant file didn't work for me; I was able to set the version in _.kitchen.yml_:

`provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  require_chef_omnibus: 12.3.0`

Comment: In Vagrant [set the chef version with vagrant-omnibus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18213542/567399).

Comment: For me, adding `require_chef_omnibus: 12.3.0` to `.kitchen.yml` results in a "missing 'name' attribute in cookbook" error. After adding the "name" attribute to `metadata.rb` in each cookbook, it works.

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution was to make sure every cookbook I was using had a "name" attribute in it with the name of the cookbook.  'redis', 'install_from', and 'metachef' cookbooks were all missing the name field from the metadata.rb

chef-client v12.3.0 helped uncover this, 12.4.1 was not showing me anything useful

Answer (score 1):

The error for me was related to two custom cookbooks that someone how had the same name in  metadata.rb correcting it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error when using a custom cookbook with a include_recipe call at the top of a recipe in that custom cookbook.
What fixed it for me is adding a metadata.rb to the custom cookbook. It should contain name and depends sections.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, I don't think it had anything to do with my recipe though, even when I didn't include it at all I had the same error. Changing chef versions solved it though.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you try to use `include_attribute 'foo'` in metadata.rb instead of attributes file.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this same error in Test Kitchen as well, though, not caused by the bug.  The error message is exceptionally cryptic for the general case of a cookbook constraint not being met (i.e. a cookbook name or version that can't be found).  In my case, from .kitchen.yml, I included an environment with specific cookbook version constraints, then specified conflicting version constraints in a Berksfile.  That was dumb, so don't do that!

Answer (score 0):

Got this due to omitting the `name` from a cookbook's `metadata.rb`. Adding the `name` fixed it.

The message we're seeing is clearly a bug in Chef and hopefully will get fixed soon, but in the meantime perhaps this can help anybody who made the same mistake as me.