# Cookbook sync fails with undefined method `cheffish' for nil:NilClass

Tags: chef-infra

Suddenly, today, Chef client starts failing with message as below. Running Chef client manually with `-l debug` doesn't give more clues.

```
[2016-08-15T16:30:26+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
  Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 7.09035028 seconds
[2016-08-15T16:30:26+02:00] ERROR: undefined method `cheffish' for nil:NilClass
[2016-08-15T16:30:26+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccess
(exit code 1)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Chef-client you are running?

It was a bug in "*12.4.0*". This error comes probably when "*name*" attribute in *metadata.rb* goes missing. It was fixed in later versions where the *metadata.rb* is validated first before the chef execution. But, it can happen with lot more of reasons apart of above.

You may also like to refer:

[undefined method "cheffish" for nil:NilClass, when provisioning chef with vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149600/undefined-method-cheffish-for-nilnilclass-when-provisioning-chef-with-vagran)

Comment: I am using 12.4.1. I btw resolved this issue by removing all cookbooks with knife cookbook delete and then running chef-client again.